# Next Silverlight 4 public release

Tags: .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

Does anyone have any idea when Microsoft might be dropping another Silverlight 4 public release?  As ScottGu has been quoted many times:

"We will be adding VS 2010 RC support for SL4 with the next public Silverlight 4 drop."

I've read speculation that there might not even be another Silverlight 4 public release until RTW.  It's painful to go back to VS2010 - Beta 2 after seeing the performance increase of the RC...but then again, we also need to push forward with Silverlight 4 development.

Anyone out there have any information on this?

Cheers,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guess would be the MIX '10 Conference on March 15-17.

They've already announced some Windows Mobile Series 7 Development news, and MIX is generally a developer/designer conference.

Answer (score 1):

With today's MIX announcement, Silverlight 4 RC, downloadable today, once again plays nice with Visual Studio RC (maybe this is obvious by now???).

Anyway - I just put up a quick blog post on it as well [here](http://rdaarchitecture.blogspot.com/2010/03/silverlight-4-rc-announced-plays-nice.html).